# Pass params to root component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

Can you pass params (like initial props) to the root component in react native?

E.G.

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'
import { Volcalc } from './app'

AppRegistry.registerComponent('volcalc_m', () => Volcalc({height:10,width:10}))
```

I am getting the error:

> Unable to execute JS call: fbBatchedBridge is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `Volcalc` is your root component, just specify the component properties within the constructor of that method:

```
class Volcalc extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            height: 10,
            width: 10,
            ...
        }

        ...
    }

    ...
```

If you want different heights depending on platform (iOS and Android), then create a root component in both `index.android.js` and `index.ios.js` rendering the `Volcalc` component in that: `<Volcalc height={10} width={10} />`.